# Error in nested subquerys

Tags: mysql, subquery, mysql-error-1054

I'm very confused by the subquery function in MySQL.

For my example I use 3 tables:

adr contains addresses
adr_acc contains groups or users that have access to the addresses
usr_grp contains the useres belonging to a group

```
select * from adr where 
adr.adr_id in
  (select ac1.adr_id from adr_acc as ac1 where
    (
      (ac1.acc_type = 'U' and ac1.acc_id = '".$s['user']."') or
      (ac1.acc_type = 'G' and ac1.acc_id in
        (select ug1.grp_id from usr_grp as ug1 where ug1.usr_id = '".$s['user']."')
      )
    )
  )
```

I get an error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'adr.adr_id' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'

what am I missing?

Comment: Can you post the (relevant) column definitions?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adr` (
  `id` varchar(20) collate latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `adr_acc` (
  `adr_id` varchar(20) collate latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `acc_type` varchar(1) collate latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `acc_id` varchar(20) collate latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`adr_id`,`acc_type`,`acc_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usr_grp` (
  `usr_id` varchar(20) collate latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  `grp_id` varchar(20) collate latin1_german1_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`usr_id`,`grp_id`)
)

Answer (score 0):

ARGGGGGGGGGGGGGG - I'm stupid, sorry for asking something incredibly stupid like that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM adr 
WHERE adr.id IN(
  SELECT ac1.adr_id
  FROM adr_acc AS ac1 
  WHERE (
      ( ac1.acc_type = 'U' AND ac1.acc_id = '".$s[' USER ']."' ) 
      OR (ac1.acc_type = 'G' AND ac1.acc_id IN (SELECT ug1.grp_id FROM usr_grp AS ug1 WHERE ug1.usr_id = '".$s[' USER ']."')
      )
    ))
```

This is the correct query.